# Cordova disable default permissions

Tags: android, cordova

I have searched the entire internet but haven't found any solution to my problem.

When I build my app and install it on my phone (Android) it asks lots of permission: `audio, edit contacts, read contacts, location, record audio, delete USB changes, send texts, ....`

I've tried to add this line to my `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

I've tried to add `uses-permissions`:

```
<platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        </config-file>
    </platform>
```

But nothing has resolved it and it still keeps asking those permissions..

Just in case my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.starter" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
  version="1.0.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />

    <!-- Ionic supports Android Jellybean and up --> 
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />

    <!-- Don't store local data in an iCloud backup. Turn this to "cloud" to enable storage 
         to be sent to iCloud. Note: enabling this could result in Apple rejecting your app.
    -->
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />


    <feature name="StatusBar">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>


</widget>
```

**EDIT:** Plugins I'm using:

```
cordova-plugin-console
cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-statusbas
ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Comment: It might be related to the plugins you are using. Which plugins do you use?

Comment: @robert I've edited my post

Comment: It's not the plugins then. Did you try to deinstall the APP first from your phone? From settings, clear cache, data, etc. I once experienced interferences with prev versions of my app (this was related to push msgs, but it's worth a try)

Comment: I have, but I still get the permissions

Comment: Two things I would try:

Comment: 1) a clean hello world example to check its not your config, e.g. cordova create dev1102 com.dev1102.Test Test1102; cd dev1102; cordova platform add android; cordova run android;  2) try it on an emulator or virtualbox to make sure its not the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding `config.json` file with list of plugins in `www folder`.

For some reason I didn't have this one.